# How to add space between label and switch?

Tags: reactjs

```
<FormControlLabel
    control={<Android12Switch checked={switchData.value} onChange={(event) => handleSwitchChange(index, event.target.checked)} /> }
   label={switchData.label}
   labelPlacement="start"
/>
```

So I need to place space between the question/text and the switch but I am not able to do so. I am using MUI switches. I have tried padding and margin styles but both failed. Also, the label starts from the switch rather than from the left side (given in the picture). If anyone has an idea please help.

[text dragging the switches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyNBY.png)

Comment: Please Add Expected behaviour, current behaviour. Provide complete UI screenshot for your question. If you are using any library for any element, better provide its name. If possible provide sandbox for your existing code.